Using sed to replace a character but not if it is in a string in bash csv file
Good morning everyone,
I have a csv and want to replace all delimiter "," with the delimiter ";", but I have to maintain the "," if it is in a string (in csv field):
Current csv
"001","User,Super","04/04/2024"

Expected csv
"001";"User,Super";"04/04/2024"

Is there a way to exclude the check if it is between a string? I would like to do this in bash with a couple of commands without the need of writing a custom loop to check every character and check the position
I tried the following command but with no success:
sed -r 's/("*,*")|,/\;/g' test.csv


People here are making simplifying assumptions, because without them processing CSVs using the likes of sed is a notoriously annoying problem. It's notorious enough that the gawk manual has a section on how to process CSVs correctly. So I suggest you just use that.

Handling general CSV files is surprisingly tricky.  See How to parse a CSV in a Bash script? for some good ways (and some bad ways, be careful) to do it.  For instance, csvtool -u ';' ... will do what you want 100% reliably for any CSV file.

I found a very neat way to do this with awk, thanks everyone!

This might work for  you (GNU sed):
sed -E ':a;s/^(("[^,"]*",)*"[^,"]*),/\1\n/;ta;y/\n,/,;/' file

Iterate along the line replacing any commas within double quotes by newlines.
When there are no more substitutions, translate newlines to commas and commas to semicolons.

I opted for using gawk since it gives me more flexibility in the following parsing but this command get the job done.
Again, thanks everyone!

Assumptions:

all fields are wrapped in double quotes
double quotes do not show up as actual data
there is no white space between the double quotes and comma (delimiter)

NOTE: if these assumptions are incorrect then OP will need to update the question with a more realistic set of sample data
A simple sed idea:
$ sed 's/","/";"/g' test.csv
"001";"User,Super";"04/04/2024"


You could use a tool that understands CSV, such as xsv:
$ xsv fmt -t ';' --quote-always <<< '"001","User,Super","04/04/2024"'
"001";"User,Super";"04/04/2024"


Since processing the CSV format is surprisingly tricky, the best way to do a task like this is to use a proven tool that is designed for processing CSV files.  One such tool, the csv module, comes as standard with Python.  This Shellcheck-clean Bash code demonstrates one way to use the Python module to process CSV data as part of a Bash program:
#! /bin/bash -p

csv='"001","User,Super","04/04/2024"'

python_code='
    import csv,sys
    r = csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter=",")
    w = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    w.writerows(r)
'

python -c "${python_code//    /}" <<<"$csv"

This program outputs:
"001";"User,Super";"04/04/2024"


"${python_code//    /}" expands to the contents of python_code with the indentation (which is used for readability) removed.  If the indentation is not removed the Python command fails with IndentationError: unexpected indent.  See Substituting part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?)) for an explanation of ${var//old/new}.
quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL is used to ensure that all CSV fields in the output are quoted.  Without it the output from the program becomes 001;User,Super;04/04/2024.  That is valid CSV (the quotes are redundant), but I'm guessing that you might want to keep them anyway.

